# Errors on building cpp binary for Windows under linux wine

Tags: wine

I'm trying to compile a binary with msbuild 2022 in linux Docker container using wine but I have some errors that prevent me from completing the process:
Target PrepareForBuild:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(512,5): warning MSB8003: The VCToolsInstallDir property is not defined. Some build tools may not be found.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(513,5): warning MSB8003: The WindowsSDKDir property is not defined. Some build tools may not be found.

Done building target "PrepareForBuild" in project "MACHINE.vcxproj".
C:\devel\MACHINE.cpp(9,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory

The VCToolsInstallDir WindowsSDKDir are defined. It can be checked with echo %VCToolsInstallDir% and %WindowsSDKDir%.
The Windows.h is present. The origin path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um is set in PATH.

What I am doing wrong regarding this config?

If anyone has a solution, please share it with me.
Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you shared your config. You are just showing warnings/error messages and ask "what is wrong with **this config**" without showing your config. Can you post your Dockerfile so that your error becomes reproducible

Comment: As the errors state, you forgot to set some environment variables. Perhaps you didn't run the compilation environment batch file that comes with the build tools.

Comment: Beside VCToolsInstallDir and WindowsSDKDir, are there other env to be set?.
Can you give me infor about the part of "run the compilation environment batch file that comes with the build tools". where can i find this file. thanks!